# How to upload an image file in multipart format to a remote server using Python's urllib library?

Tags: python, urllib

I'm working on unnoffical python API for [CharacterAI](https://beta.character.ai/), and currently working on function that uploading image to server. I've found a fetch request to server that uploads image to server, here how it looks like in curl command:

```
curl 'https://beta.character.ai/chat/upload-image/' \
  -H 'authority: beta.character.ai' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'authorization: Token <my token>' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryXotaCBORB09RcYoP' \
  -H 'cookie: _ga=GA1.2.2076496951.1685200794; _gid=GA1.2.2097971597.1685200794; __cf_bm=UzpnRqJDrimTvSK5UDC6mfon3jvneYw7m5aJYzSzI5Q-1685200790-0-AWcQrB3E5NSNXWFxaD60Zuwb7H0AhPuOmMPnz3NVXxQNNsDkffyPWxk4AeC1lvhyie22ruRO16vohXz6jJaaRzhiURhMvSFZs/xjpeP0GbwSWkk5KSUaT82rAekWsHysJMq+TDkLmXVxzzhpTe+L2Wc=; messages=.eJyLjlaKj88qzs-Lz00tLk5MT1XSMdAxMtVRCi5NTgaKpJXm5FQqFGem56WmKGTmKSQWK3iWFPtWBqQWATUl5oTkF5WUFqXqKekoKcXqjBo2atioYaOGjRo2atigMywWAHoxZ2E:1q2vhx:IyE0968fQwUVX_EqgwabVlPytanTyoRtQuoeBnIUBhQ; sessionid=9vfvfjlnh90wl2d2eh3ucibovm2xpzii; csrftoken=WNlFNkez6TjYqFCR9kaF3uF4s3BWts7w; _gat=1; __cfwaitingroom=ChhtSVd1cThJUHpKSWFmdmx1a3MxMWp3PT0SrAJEaXBTalQ0eTc4eWVKMkg5TmliS2haMFpGV3FoSWQ0dmhMTW4zSXdpZms1cjliUm9TMmMzdTVCaFhmb2VSQk4xNzJUdnR2U3N3ajN4THpacFpRdzNxYmxuek50T0ZueERRcnY1V0xPNGJxTE5Zb2U1YlhIdmJWZVM5emFkZnBWc0xkdzlCa3lxK2VGelU5WC9RN1hCbXpHNkVrdDVhbUhKZTY2VUlibWpDa28wTFQ5M3h1eTJRL1RuOGdSclU0QVUyelk4Tlc0NXVCenliTHBIT0lqSkJEUmtlT29QcGpib3AzaE1DMktzOFVlY29QOXcxZ3FGbFRZZ0xlNU12cnByM2ZHeVc5V2g0MGwwQXRhNkpkVmp3SXp3d0pNRWRNUk9LQ2orNGQwRHpFcz0%3D' \
  -H 'origin: https://beta.character.ai' \
  -H 'referer: https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=EEI6sjnddRIJTVC59MODiYjL0-JyDIVI2IEGLkPx2Jk' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Not_A Brand";v="24", "Opera GX";v="98"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/98.0.0.0' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundaryXotaCBORB09RcYoP\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image_2023-05-27_182021719.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryXotaCBORB09RcYoP--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

And of course, my **sendImage** function:

```
    async def sendImage(self, image="", text=""):
        await self.ping()
        imagepath = "image.png"
        image = open(imagepath, 'rb')

        response = self._request('https://beta.character.ai/chat/upload-image/', {}) # Some way to send that image
        print(response)
```

My **_request** function:

```
    async def _request(self, url, body={}):
        request = urllib.request.Request(url, json.dumps(body).encode() if body else None, self._getHeaders())
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
            output = json.loads(response.read().decode())
            return output
        except Exception:
                return False
```

Mainly, i use **_request** function for checking if cookies are valid and creating conversation, so it may not be correct way to upload image.

I tried use many other libraries like requests and http, but for some reason they don't even access site, even with correct cookies and headers.

I tried to edit my function like this:

```
async def sendImage(self, image="", text=""):
        await self.ping()
        file_path = 'image.png'
        content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
        boundary = 'wL36Yn8xjy1587523677jy'

        def headers():
            return {
                'authority': 'beta.character.ai',
                'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
                'authorization': f'Token {self.userToken}',
                'content-type': f'multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary}',
                'cookie': f'{self.cookies}',
                'origin': 'https://beta.character.ai',
                'referer': 'https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=EEI6sjnddRIJTVC59MODiYjL0-JyDIVI2IEGLkPx2Jk',
                'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="112", "Not_A Brand";v="24", "Opera";v="98"',
                'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/98.0.0.0'
            }

        data = []
        data.append('--' + boundary)
        data.append(f'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="{os.path.basename(file_path)}"')
        data.append(f'Content-Type: {content_type}')
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            data.append(f.read())
        data.append('')
        data.append('--' + boundary + '--')
        data.append('')
        body = b'\r\n'.join(map(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, bytes) else x.encode(), data))

        req = urllib.request.Request('https://beta.character.ai/chat/upload-image/', data=body, headers=headers())
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        print(response)
```

but it returns `b'{"status": "NOT_OK", "error": "Image file missing"}'`.
I have no other ideas how to make that feature, GPT-4 can't help me as well. I'm expecting status code 200 from server at least, to know if code can upload image to server.

I would be very thankful if anyone have some ways to fix the code, if you need any other blocks of my code, ask me, thanks in advance.